# Updating state array with a component as a value

Tags: reactjs

How can I include a component in a state when updating? I have an icon and this is what I tried:

```
useStates((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  iconState: <MyIcon /> + "Some text",
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert `iconState` to function and use it just as other components.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function MyIcon(props) {
  return <div>ICON</div>;
}

function App() {
  const [states, useStates] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    useStates((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      iconState: () => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <MyIcon /> Some text
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    }));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {states.iconState && <states.iconState />}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```